# Issue with PIVOTING two columns at the same time and one includes a datetime column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, pivot

I have a table used for attendance tracking, so I can track the arrival time of a person and the date in which they have arrived. I'm now trying to get a report based on that data and have created a view for it below. I have used the PIVOT function to split up the dates and it works without the column highlighted in bold below. The only issue is that I'm trying to PIVOT on a second column called **DeviceFirstScannedTime** which returns a datetime value, once that gets added the original PIVOT query doesn't group correctly.

Using SQL Server 2012

**Current Query for PIVOTING**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [Code] AS [CB Code], [Lastname], [Firstname], CompanyName AS [Company], DeviceScannedDateOnly, [Code], **DeviceFirstScannedTime**
FROM [dbo].[vLDN23_DailyReportForPivot]) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT (Count([Code]) FOR DeviceScannedDateOnly IN ([06/02/2023], [07/02/2023])) AS PivotTable;
```

What it shows without the DeviceFirstScannedTime column added, shows it will pivot on DeviceScannedDateOnly and Split the dates correctly (it groups the two scans in the original source table and pivots them);

| CB Code | Lastname | Firstname | Company | 06/02/23 | 07/02/23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WSSPS24HX6 | Smith | Bob | Stan | 1 | 1 |

With the datetime column added I get the data separated;

| CB Code | Lastname | Firstname | Company | DeviceFirstScannedTime | 06/02/23 | 07/02/23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WSSPS24HX6 | Smith | Bob | Stan | 2023-02-06 10:12:0060 | 1 | 0 |
| WSSPS24HX6 | Smith | Bob | Stan | 2023-02-07 13:87:0000 | 0 | 1 |

Data is now split which isn't ideal for reporting..

What I'm trying to do is this

| Firstname | Company | 06 Scanned time | 06/02/23 | 07 Scanned Time | 07/02/23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Stan | 2023-02-06 10:12:0060 | 1 | 2023-02-07 13:87:0000 | 1 |

I've removed the first couple of columns to make it more readable but essentially I'm trying to PIVOT on two columns and split the table accordingly all into one line.

Is that possible with a datatime column?

Comment: What does your data look like *before* you `PIVOT` it? Have you tried using conditional aggregation? It's far less restrictive than the `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: Forget pivot and do it manually. Plus, what are you looking for, first scanned time per day or what.